What is this book on Katie's bookshelf?
In The Secret Life of Pets, what is the green book on Katie's bookshelf? Alternately what is the symbol on the book? I feel like I've seen it before, but can't place it.


Well, we know another book on the shelf (titled something like "Highly _____ Body") is written by a certain "Dr. R. Userious":

In other words, R U serious? These aren't real books. And that just appears to be a generic cloud picture on the back cover.
The titles of the other books on the shelves that I can read (somewhat) are: "Interior ____" and "The Highly Ec____ed". A second after this, you can see "Green Table — Cooking Vegetarian" on the counter, although the book Duke catches is clearly labeled "Gluttony". "Song Writing" can be seen in the background.
We see other bookshelves in the movie. What I can read from another one is (from left to right):

Joel Corcia
Lights and Darks — Ludovic Gavillet
Anael
White Boxes
Ludo Gavillet
Optimism — Joel Corcia
White Boxes
H.O.M.E. — Claire Lentz

The names here are significant. Anael Bouin was the set designer for the movie. Joël Corcia    did color key. Claire Lentz was a color artist. Ludovic Gavillet was another color artist.
In yet another bookshelf, the titles I can read (again, left to right) are:

Beagles
Downtown New York
English Gardens
Great Lakes
The History of Ellis Island
The Roaring Twenties
Lighthouses

While these look like the could be real titles, searching did not bring up any books that looked like them. In any case, they are super generic titles.
